# Hibernate c3p0 configuration

Tags: mysql, hibernate, c3p0, myeclipse

I am using Hibernate c3p0 configuration for connection pooling.
some times my appliaction has exhausted, is there any problem with my code. can any one please help me."my code is like this".

'

```
   <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
   <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
   <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
   <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">20</property>
   <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
   <property name="connection.provider_class">
      org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
   </property>'
```

Comment: What is application is exhausted ?

Comment: there is response from server

Answer (score 2):

You may have a Connection leak. Please consider trying c3p0 config parameters [unreturnedConnectionTimeout](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#unreturnedConnectionTimeout) and [debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces). See the discussion [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients).